# Wrap text on many lines

Tags: html, css

I have a text over many lines. Example:

[image: CSS: wrap text on many lines]

Can the text be adapted to the div?

In this example, after the word "text" there is a space with color blue. In CSS there is a method to avoid the blue space after the word "text"?

If I have several texts with different lengths, is there a way to generalize this behavior?

```css
.box {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 200px;
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 40px;
}

.label {
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<h1>My First Heading</h1>

<div class="box">
  I'm a box.
  <div class="label">
    I'm a label without a text wrapped.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: no you cannot do this

Answer (score 1):

To avoid space after text and align it property to both side, use [`text-align`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-align) css property.

[image: View on Codepen]

```css
.box {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 200px;
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 40px;
}
.label {
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
  background-color: blue;
  text-align: justify;
}
```

```html
<h1>My First Heading</h1>

<div class="box">
    I'm a box.
    <div class="label">
        I'm a label without a text wrapped.
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I cannot justify the text

Comment: You could also use `word-break` to avoid blue space

Answer (score 0):

you could use a `margin-right: <unit of measument>;` in order to remove the excess blue though this would not be very responsive if the size of that box is going to change.

Comment: If I have several texts of different lengths, is there a way to generalize this behavior?

Comment: I'm not sure that there is to be honest. Seems like such a trivial thing to.